# Rails before action check if admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed devise and I've added to the user table a record or column (I'm not sure how to call it) a admin:boolean and by default it's false

In my routes.rb I have created this /admin link

```
get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
```

and I'm not sure how to show it only for admin

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action: I have no idea what to write here

  def index
  end

end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this in your controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
    before_action :is_admin?

  def index

  end


    # it will call before every action on this controller
    def is_admin?
      # check if user is a admin
      # if not admin then redirect to where ever you want 
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin? 
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, should the is_admin method should be inside private?

Comment: Yes you can set it in private.

Comment: you saved my day so you bet I'm going to accept it, thank you so much!

Comment: this answer is assuming the user is logged in. You should add a `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the line before to catch the case when the user is not signed in.